# Making a gitlab repo read only/give members Guest permissions

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab

I have a private repo on GitLab. It is with in a group with other repos that I do not want to change. I want to retire just this repo so the commits and merge requests can be referenced but not pushed to/changed/etc. Read only basically.

If I go to the repo (Project) Settings > Members it lists all the members of the group. There is no way here to set permissions specific to this repo here though. They are inherited from the group member permissions.

I have found I can go to Settings > Repository > Protected branches and add one with '*' and set allowed to merge/push to 'No one'. This doesn't stop merge requests/issues etc though.

Am I missing something or do I have to make a new group and move over the repo so I can then set 'Guest' permissions on that new group's members? There is no way to override the group member permissions at a repo level?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [archive](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#archiving-a-project) the repository.

Comment: Spot on, thank you! Felt like I had to be missing something.

Comment: As of December 2023 the link https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#archiving-a-project is broken and redirects to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/working_with_projects.html, which does not contain instructions for archiving a project.

Answer (score 0):

In GitLab Enterprise Edition v16.5 here is what works for me:

In my project I navigate to Settings > General > Advanced > Expand and press the "Archive project" button.

As of December 2023 the link for the documentation for this in gitlab is https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/migrate_projects.html#archive-a-project